# Drag & Drop to Hamon.ie in Outlook creates a new version instead of new document

Tags: drag-and-drop, outlook, harmon.ie

When I drag & drop an attachment from an Outlook email to the Hamon.ie for Outlook window, I expect harmon.ie to add the document to the active library/folder.

But if I drop the document over an *existing* document in Hamon.ie, it creates a new version of that document instead of adding a new document. There is no indication of the Harmon.ie behaviour and it took some time before I figure out what was happening.

Is there an option that would make Harmon.ie ask if the user wants to add a new version to the existing document or create a new document.

If not, where should users drop the file when the file list is full of documents? Dropping in the header does not work. Do I have to tell my users to drop the document in the few white pixels at the bottom of the list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find additional details about the "Add as new version" feature in harmon.ie User Guide under Uploading SharePoint Documents section(https://harmon.ie/documentation/sharepoint/outlook/uploading#replaceexisting) section.

As detailed in the user guide, following UI prompt occurs when using this feature

> When uploading to a document library with versioning support: 1.Drag the document onto the document you want to overwrite and hold for 2 seconds. A tooltip displays: Add as a new version to .

The following registry key can be applied to deactivate this feature.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\AddNewVersionDelay]

@="0"

Create AddNewVersionDelay key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs and set its default value to 0 (zero).

Comment: Thank you Maksim for your reply. Actually, there is no prompt and user is not holding the document. I did not mention that user wo took this to my attention today was dropping the document to a SP 2007 Library. But I'm pretty sure this happended earlier on a SP 2013 library. I'll check for the registry key and be back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Confirmed. The delay 0 disable the drag and drop feature but let the user select the "Add a new version..." when required. Exactly what I want.

In the situation I described in the question, I was doing a demo and I probably kept the pointer over an icon for more that two seconds just to let users see what I was doing. And I did not notice the "Add new version" message.